# Javascript stopped activating

Tags: javascript, html, css

So my javascript has inexplicably stopped working.  I'm not quite sure what I did but any help would be greatly appreciated.  thanks!  I really should be using VC, I guess this is the wake up call

```
<head style="overflow-x: hidden">
    <title>Dupont Studios</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="waypoints.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 400px)" href="mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 401px)" href="style.css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        // Do our DOM lookups beforehand
        var nav_container = $(".nav-container");
        var nav = $("nav");
        nav_container.waypoint({
        handler: function(direction) {
        nav_container.toggleClass('sticky', direction=='down');

        }
        });
        });

    </script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $("li.nav-item").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).children().attr("href")).offset().top + "px"}, {duration: 500, easing: "swing"
        });
        return false;
        });

    </script>
</head>
```

errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.js:351
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function waypoints.js:25
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'waypoint'
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Are you debugging with the developer tools?

Comment: You really should always have the developer console open when you're working on any web software.  Even if you don't know what an error means, having the error will be of tremendous assistance to people here trying to help.

Comment: sorry, ill update the errors now

Answer (score 3):

you need to load first jquery then jquery ui then waypoints

Comment: that worked! well kinda, the sticky header is working now but the live scrolling still seems to be messed up

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
nav_container.waypoint
```

There is no method `waypoint` on jQuery collection.

Moreover `jquery-ui` should be placed after `jQuery` not before it.

The last error for now is in `waypoints.js` in line 25 - you are trying to call some function which is undefined yet.

Answer (score -1):

One reason could be that you have deactivated the javascript from your browsers.. Find it in settings of your browser and activate javascript.

After your errors, it looks like the syntax is error is in the jquery ui file, please replace it with the latest one and give it a try.